# two tables referencing a single table through a referencing table

Tags: mysql, database, entity-framework, normalization

i created a database for the categorizing of people who apply for public housing, one of this categories is does the aplicant or a family member of the applicant have a disability, but i have struggled with normalizing the table: i've studied different answers in the site and this is the best option i came with:

```
                  family
                    M|1
        applicant-1--|--1-family member
            1 |          1 |
            1 |          1 |
                disabled
                  1 |
                  M | 
         disabled by disability
                  1 |
                  M |
              disability
                  1 |
                  1 |
            type of disability
```

applicant

- id applicant (PK)
- id disabled (fk)

family member

- id family (PK)
- id disabled (fk)

dissabled

- id dissabled (PK)

disabled by disability

- id disabled by disability (PK)
- id disabled (fk)
- id disability (fk)

disability

- id disability (PK)
- id name disability (fk)
- id type dissability (fk)

type of disability

- id type disability (PK)
- name type disability

The intended use of this is that an applicant or a family member can list as many disabilities as he has. is this is the best way to simplify the querys and is it correctly normalized?

Comment: dont know the others, but if you can explain the tables and the relationships among them verbally, it would help me more to understand.

Comment: ok 'DISABLED' gives 'APLICANT' and 'FAMILY MEMBER' a ''disabled id'' that is stored as foreign key in 'APLICANT' and 'FAMILY MEMBER', the same ''disabled id'' is stored in 'DISABLED BY DISABILITY' so it can be repeated in as many rows as disabilities it has. 'DISABILITY' has a list of ''disability name'' and ''disability type'' and 'TYPE OF DISABILITY' stores the names of the disability types.        The most important part is the relation of 'APLICANT' and 'FAMILY MEMBER' to 'DISABLED BY DISABILITY' through 'DISABLED' ensuring i don't have put aplicant or family member in a single row

Comment: each `APPLICANT` is also a `FAMILY MEMBER`, is that right? what is the relationship between them?

Comment: sorry i didn't explaint it. an APLICANT has several FAMILY MEMBERS and they are related throug a table called FAMILY, APLICANT stores FAMILY's PK and FAMILY stores FAMILY MEMBER's PK.  an aplicant can have many family members but a family member can only be related to a single aplicant

Answer (score 0):

How about this: Each `APPLICANT` can have many `FAMILYMEMBER`s and also itself a `FAMILYMEMBER`. One member of a family, can apply for `HOUSEAPPLICATION`, this is why MemberId is PK in `HOUSEAPPLICATION`.

You need relationship ONLY between DISABLEDPEOPLE and FAMILYMEMBERS. In DISABLEDPEOPLE table you will have composite key (DisabilityId, MemberId).

**FAMILYMEMBERS**

MemberId, ConnectedApplicantId, Relationship, Name, Surname

**HOUSEAPPLICATION**

MemberId[PK&FK], ApplicantName, Date

**DISABLEDPEOPLE**

DisabilityId, MemberId, DateApproved

**DISABILITY**

DisabilityId, DisabilityName, DisabilityTypeId

**DISABLITYTYPES**

DisabilityTypeId, DisabilityTypeName

Comment: you missed how to assign a dissability to a family member, family members can have dissabilities too. I had tought before if maybe it would be a god idea to create a single table called 'PERSON' instead of 'APLICANT' and 'FAMILY MEMBER' but i've never worked with recursing tables before and it would give me troubles with other parts of the database

Comment: so you mean, familymembers apply to get disabled status ? I did not get the logic. So, why not just have one APPLICANT table? Do you want to know the family relationships of applicants?

Comment: yes, i want to know if the applicant is disabled himself and/or if his family members have a disability.

Comment: @AndresMiguel please see my update. I added a Family table. For each applicant, you will need to create a Family record. Using FAMILYMEMBERS you will add new applicants to an existing family. This way you can still record everyone's disabilities while knowing their family connections.

Comment: i drawed the E-R model of your proposal but it still lacks a way to assign a disability to a family member, the relation between aplicant and family member is not very important to me now becuse i have a table like APPLICANTFAMILYMEMBERS and the type of relationship is already specified in a field of 'family member' as 'type of kinship'.  My big concern is trying to assing multiple disabilities to both APLICANT and FAMILY MEMBER but mantaining the 2NF

Comment: @AndresMiguel I forgot to delete `APPLICANTFAMILYMEMBERS` table. Please see my design again. From practical perspective, when a user is added to the system firstime, you create his family information first time as well and define him as the Leader of the family (see `LeaderId`). Then, you can define this applicant's disability information. Later, if another applicant from the same family needs to be added, you can add the new application to `FAMILYMEMBERS` table and also define his disability-related information. Makes sense?

Comment: this should explain the idea i was working on better http://s28.postimg.org/86sfna7xp/dissabled.png

Comment: can you explain to me how your application will work, what will be logic? What will happen first? I still do not think that family should be related to disability. Family table should only keep information about family connections, each families cities phone, etc. Each  family member can be an application for the disability. The first applicant would be the Leader of the family, that is all. Applicant table is where you keep also name, etc.

Comment: i dont understand well what you mean just reading, if its not too much of a bother could you do a little diagram and post it please?      an aplicant cansolicit a house and he also provides a list of his family members, each family member is automatically banned from being an apliant themselves.   if an aplicant or one of his members has a disability he has more priority for geting public housing, providing that he already gave the documentation that proves his disability and that of his family members if they are disabled (all of this is already diagramed and works well),

Comment: @AndresMiguel I updated my post based on your description. I have some differences from my original version, and also from your design. Some of the constraints you mentioned can be done in the application. I hope it will make sense to you as well..